# Is there any way share state between

Tags: reactjs

I have four components: `Panel`, `PanelHeader`, `PanelBody`, `PanelFooter` they are composed as following:

```js
<Panel>
    <PanelHeader>
        some title
    </PanelHeader>
    <PanelBody>
        <div>
            main content
        </div>
    </PanelBody>
    <PanelFooter>
        footer content
    </PanelFooter>
</Panel>
```

I also have multiple routes, where I want to see that `Panel`, but with different content.

An obvious solution is to create components for each of routes and each of those components will have their own `Panel`.

But in my case I want to add some morphing animation between routes (change the height of panel, slide body, fade footer etc.). To achieve this I need to render all the contents to exactly the same `Panel`, `PanelHeader`, `PanelBody`, `PanelFooter` instances, so the solution above won't work.

So I need to split my route component into three components for each `PanelXXX` and the problem is that those components need to react on events of each other.

There are the following points so far:

- I can't create another one mediator component to control those three partial components, because I will not be able to access its API till it will be rendered (so I can't implement getter methods e.g. getHeader()).
- I can connect them all to redux, but it seams too complicated.
- Another one solution is to create non-React object to share the state, but in this case I will need to clean up after this object to overcome memory leaks. The connection with redux will also be tricky. This approach looks not so clean to me.
- I can also cheat with transparent background, so that I can have one `Panel` but multiple `PanelHeader`s etc. But in this case I will need to spread the knowledge about animation to all the child components.

Does anybody knows any other approach to do that in React? Or should I choose one from the points above?

Comment: Leaving this comment for people who come here, trying to decide whether or not to use Redux, generally.  I found the create react app template, installed with npx create-react-app my-app --template redux to be really helpful in learning redux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the scenario you are describing and the questions you pose are the exact rationalizations for using Flux. Redux is one option. We used a plain vanilla Flux implementation using the original Facebook library and we have had great success. It has a steep learning curve, but once you get your head around it, issues like the one you are facing just fit right in to the infrastructure.

Comment: ok. I will mark your answer as correct, because the only one option I see here is to bind all partial components through global shared state. But I've expected that someone will suggest a way to solve the problem using some intermediate, local state.

Comment: @SleepWalker I understand completely, but what you are suggesting is an anti-pattern and using Flux, once you get to know it, makes these issues very easy to manage.

Comment: nope. Store does not need to know about component specific state and communication. Store is for business logic specific state. Normally you use component's state to store some intermediate state till you collect all the data needed to trigger an action. This action will be triggered in some event handler. But in my case I have a button (event handler) in one component, and UI for gathering the data in other component and using Store in this place is a bad smell, but I can't find better way to solve this issue yet.

Comment: @SleepWalker - Not exactly. What you are saying is true of parent and child components. Sibling components should not control each other directly, if you buy in to the Flux architecture. The pattern is that the button component triggers an action and the action is dispatched to the stores. The store updates data and triggers a change event. The other sibling subscribes to the change event, gets the new data and updates the view as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could benefit from using `this.props.children`.

*Router*

```
<Router history={createBrowserHistory()}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={DefaultView} />
        <Route path="foopath" component={FooView} />
        <Route path="barpath" component={BarView} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

*App.js*

```
...

render: function() {
    return (
        <Panel>
            {this.props.children}
        </Panel>
    );
}

...
```

*DefaultView.js*

```
render: function() {
    <div>
        <PanelHeader>
            FooHeader
        </PanelHeader>
        <PanelBody>
            FooContent
        </PanelBody>
        <PanelFooter>
            FooFooter
        </PanelFooter>
    </div>
}
```

You can read more about React's *children* [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#children).

Comment: sorry, but I meant, that I need singleton `PanelHeader`, `PanelBody`, `PanelFooter` too. I've update question to be more clear.